# how to upload image and insert into database into codeigniter 3

Tags: image, codeigniter, insert

i try to upload image and insert it into database but it's not working.
there is no any error showing in page and image is also not uploading or inserting into database,
please, give me a solution for that how can i solved this problem?

my code is here,
the code of controller is here, `enter code here`

```
public function add_product()
{
            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
            $config['max_size'] = 100;
            $config['max_width'] = 1024;
            $config['max_height'] = 768;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            $input_name = "product_image";
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload($input_name))
            {
                $data['items'] = $this->data_model->get_data_info('product_id','product');
                $this->load->view('product',$data);
            }
            else
            {
                   $image_info = $this->upload->data();
                       $data = array(
                            'product_name'=>$this->input->post('product'),
                            'product_pic'=>$image_info['file_name'],
                             'description'=>$this->input->post('description')
                            );

                            $query = $this->data_model->add_data($data,'product');
                            if($query == TRUE){
                                echo "product added";
                                $data['items'] = $this->data_model->get_data_info('product_id','product');
                                $this->load->view('product',$data);
                            }else{
                                echo"product already exists";
                                $data['items'] = $this->data_model->get_data_info('product_id','category');
                                $this->load->view('product',$data);
                            } 

                }
}
```

**model :**

```
    public function add_data($data,$table){
        $result = $this->db->get_where($table,$data);
        $query = (bool)$result->num_rows();
        if(!$query){
           if($this->db->insert($table,$data)){
                return TRUE;
            }else{
                return FALSE;
            } 
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }
}
```

Comment: Try this `if (!$this->upload->do_upload($input_name)){ print_r($this->upload->display_errors()); exit;` And tell what is the result of this

Comment: given path is not proper but now it's working fine. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

controller code

```
 function add_product() {
    if (!is_dir('./Uploads/')) {
        mkdir('./Uploads/', 0777, TRUE);
    }
    if (!empty($_FILES['product_image'])) {
        $config['upload_path'] = './Uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width'] = '1024';
        $config['max_height'] = '768';
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
        $config['file_name'] = date('U') . '_' . $_FILES['product_image']['name'];
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('product_image')) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            print_r($error);
            die;
        } else {
            if ($this->upload->do_upload('product_image')) {
                $image_data = $this->upload->data();
                $full_path = $config['file_name'];
                $data["product_pic"] = $full_path;
                $query = $this->data_model->add_data($data, 'product');
                if ($res == TRUE) {
                    echo "product added";
                    $data['items'] = $this->data_model->get_data_info('product_id', 'product');
                    $this->load->view('product', $data);
                } else {
                    echo"product already exists";
                    $data['items'] = $this->data_model->get_data_info('product_id', 'category');
                    $this->load->view('product', $data);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $this->load->view('product');
}
```

model code

```
function add_data($data, $table) {    
if ($query = $this->db->insert($table,$data)) {
    $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
    return $insert_id;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

}